# Set distance between spans using margin

Tags: css, xhtml, layout, margin, html

Here is two spans(in real life a lot of spans) situated at the web page. I would like to set the distance betwwen them. I want to use margin-bottom attribute for this, but I can't see any affect of using it. The spans are still on the previous position. That is wrong.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .position, .name{
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .position{
            margin-bottom: 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="position">Designer</span><br/>
    <span class="name">John Smith</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`span` is an inline element, not a block element, and they don't respect (vertical) `margin`. You can use padding or make the span `display:inline-block;` and then use margins. The latter is now supported in most somewhat newer browsers.

Comment: I agree only partially with you when you say that span does not respect margin. It does respect margin, but only left and right. Not top and bottom.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, CSS2.1 [specifies inline elements to respect horizontal margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting). Here the problem was with vertical alignment, so margin won't work.

Comment: I'm in a rush right now but padding-top on span did not work for me. I ended up using a div.  Owell.

Comment: It does not respect horizontal margins fully. auto option doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I would say line-height is what you are looking for.